# Why dev tools don't understand closures?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Can someone explain me why Dev Tools of Chrome (maybe other browsers as well - I haven't bothered with checking) don't see variables up the chain?

so if I have something like this:

```
function wholeKit(kaboodle) {
    kaboodle.forEach((k)=> {
      k.parts.map((p)=> {
         // console.log(kaboodle, k)    
        debugger;   
      })   
    })  
}
```

At the breakpoint Chrome will see value of `p`, but won't see `kaboodle` and `k`. They would be `undefined`. But if I uncomment the line above the breakpoint - magically those variables will be no longer undefined. How so?

[jsbin for those who can't mentally digest ES6](http://jsbin.com/beduxuxuce/1/edit?js,output)

upd: apparently that's how browser's garbage collector works, those variables that not being used get scraped. Now I'm curious if there's a way to tweak GC, for when DevTools are open?

Comment: Sounds like its optimizing away unused variables and is not something related to the garbage collector. The garbage collector wont lead to that "undefined reference" error and I know for a fact that its actually not very smart and its easy to get memory leaks in Javascript.

Comment: Either way, I think you should check if this isn't already filed as a bug in Chrome. kaboodle is out of scope if you use it in the console but you can still find it if you look at the "Call Stack" pane.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has syntax errors. The forEach and map are missing a closing parenthesis and Chrome does not support the ES6 arrow syntax for lambdas.

When I changed the callbacks to regular functions and added the missing parenthesis everything worked just fine.

```
function wholeKit(kaboodle) {
    kaboodle.forEach(function(k){
        k.parts.map(function(p){
            console.log(kaboodle, k)    
            debugger;   
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Before blindly posting an answer, you should at least read the question. 

`function wholeKit(kaboodle) {
    kaboodle.forEach(function(k){
        k.parts.map(function(p){
             debugger;   
        });
    });
}
wholeKit([
  {parts:['a','b','c'] }
])`
Run this and you'd see that k and kaboodle are undefined

Comment: Before blindly commenting on an answer, you should at least read it. If you fix the closure issues mentioned by this user, you'd see that `k` and `kaboodle` are no longer undefined.

Comment: Do you understand why console.log commented out in my post?

Comment: I didn't blindly answer, I actually tested it. But now that you gave another example I managed to reproduce it.  Yeah, this is very weird. One workaround that worked for me is adding an `eval("")` statement next to the "debugger" to disable any of the more fancy optimizations the JS engine might be doing